# cifs mount is triggering NAS login/logout every couple minutes

Tags: samba, fstab, nas

I have Asustor NAS server and `proxmox` installed on other server.

On `proxmox` I have installed `plex` and mounted some CIFS resources in `fstab` for `plex`. I see that, even if `plex` is disabled, every (about) 9 minutes NAS is logging that `samba` user is logged in and logged out. With unmounted CIFS resources that log is not showing.

The problem with that is that my NAS is not heavly used. For most of the time disks should be in sleep mode but login and logout of smb user is blocking disk hibernation.

Is there any way to fix that? Maybe using some other way to mount resources?

fstab
[image]

NAS log
[image]

Proxmox backup cifs
[image]

Asustor diagnostic tool output

```
"The following processes continually access hard disks, preventing them from entering into hibernation. You can manually close these processes."
"mdadm"
"lighttpd"
"logmand"
"More information:"

"Time","Service","Description","Storage","Status"
"2024/01/28 13:05","mdadm","Storage Management Tools","Volume1","READ"
"2024/01/28 13:05","mdadm","Storage Management Tools","Volume1","READ"
"2024/01/28 13:05","mdadm","Storage Management Tools","Volume1","READ"
"2024/01/28 13:05","mdadm","Storage Management Tools","Volume1","READ"
"2024/01/28 13:04","mdadm","Storage Management Tools","Volume1","READ"
"2024/01/28 13:04","mdadm","Storage Management Tools","Volume1","READ"
"2024/01/28 13:04","mdadm","Storage Management Tools","Volume1","READ"
"2024/01/28 13:04","mdadm","Storage Management Tools","Volume1","READ"
"2024/01/28 13:04","mdadm","Storage Management Tools","Volume1","READ"
"2024/01/28 13:04","mdadm","Storage Management Tools","Volume1","READ"
"2024/01/28 13:04","mdadm","Storage Management Tools","Volume1","READ"
"2024/01/28 13:03","mdadm","Storage Management Tools","Volume1","READ"
"2024/01/28 13:03","mdadm","Storage Management Tools","Volume1","READ"
"2024/01/28 13:03","mdadm","Storage Management Tools","Volume1","READ"
"2024/01/28 13:03","mdadm","Storage Management Tools","Volume1","READ"
"2024/01/28 13:03","mdadm","Storage Management Tools","Volume1","READ"
"2024/01/28 13:03","mdadm","Storage Management Tools","Volume1","READ"
```

Comment: Why would the login/logout inhibit sleep? That doesn't touch any of the days on the storage.  Have you verified this is actually the problem?

Comment: Yes, it looks that this is the problem. When I unmount cifs, disks are going to hibernation. With mounted volumes I don't see any disk hibernation at all.

Comment: But that's still not the saying that whatever phenomenon is being logged on your NAS is what is helping your disks running! All we can say is that it's not happening when the disks aren't mounted. Also a gain of knowledge, but it's not telling us what it is that keeps your Nas from suspending the disks.

Comment: I added some screens. This is my problem that it don;t understand what is the reason. I had plex and now i desabled it and unmount all shares used by plex and when i enable proxmox backup via cifs i see lot mount logs

Comment: I tried now to mount nfs instead of cifs. I will look if that will help.

Comment: @ConstantineA.B. still the same. I started NAS diagnostic tool and madm process is accessing disk. I'm wondering how to go further and verify what is that. Can i monitor directory access by process on my node which have mounted my nfs share?

Comment: @ConstantineA.B. do you have any idea how can i check what is causing that disks are not going to hibernation when mounted?